# Why doesn't replace () change all occurrences?

Tags: python, replace

I have the following code:

```
dna = "TGCGAGAAGGGGCGATCATGGAGATCTACTATCCTCTCGGGGTATGGTGGGGTTGAGA"

print(dna.count("GAGA"))

dna = dna.replace("GAGA", "AGAG")

print(dna.count("GAGA"))
```

Replace does not replace all occurrences. Could somebody help my in understanding why it happened?

Comment: `replace` works. The two strings overlap. This means replacing `GAGA` with `AGAG` can easily *create* the same patter. That replacement in `GAGAA` will produce `AGAGA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did make all replacements (that's what `.replace()` does in Python unless specified otherwise), but some of these replacements inadvertently introduced new instances of GAGA. Take the beginning of your string:

```
TGCGAGAA
```

There's GAGA at indices 3-6. If you replace that with AGAG, you get

```
TGCAGAGA
```

So the last G from that AGAG, together with the subsequent A that was already there before, forms a new GAGA.

Answer (score 3):

It replaces all occurences. That might lead to new occurences (look at your replacement string!).

I'd say, logically, all is fine.

You could repeat this `replace` `while dna.count("GAGA") > 0` , but: that sounds not like what you *should* be doing. (I bet you really just want to do one round of replacement to simulate something specific happening. Not a genetics expert at all though.)

Answer (score 0):

Replacements does not occur "until exhausted"; they occur when a substring is matched *in your original* string.

Consider the following from your string:

```
>>> a = "TGCGAGAA"
>>> a.replace("GAGA", "AGAG")
'TGCAGAGA'
>>>
```

The replacement does not happen again, since the original string did *not* match `GAGA` in that location.

If you want to do the replacement until no match is found, you can wrap it in a loop:

```
>>> while a.count("GAGA") > 0:  # you probably don't want to use count here if the string is long because of performance considerations
...   a = a.replace("GAGA", "AGAG")
...
>>> a
'TGCAAGAG'
```